# Additional fields or intersection table

Tags: database-design

I have a `domains` table and each domain belongs to a `contact`. Additionally you can assign 3 extra `contacts` with different roles **admin**, **tech** and **billing** ,*those are not mandatory*.

My first thought was to add three extra fields in my *domains* table.

[image: first thought]

but then I thought it was better to create an intersection table.

[image: second thought]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an intersection table is a cleaner and more flexible design.

With extra columns you are limited to the number of instances you can include (one per foreign key column).  Also, the types of instances are limited to those given by your FK columns.  Making any changes requires a table design change.  Also, since your roles are optional, you may have a lot of nulls in your FKs.  Having sparsely populated columns rubs some people the wrong way.  Whether this is a real design problem or just a "code smell" is debatable and depends on how you actually populate your table.

With an intersection table, you can either use constraints to enforce a single instance per type or you can allow multiple instances per type.  That might prove useful in the future if you start having contacts share a role.

Also, with an intersection table, you can create a new role without having to make a table design change.  This could save you a lot of work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In both approach you  see the table will have all columns to gather where for one column you will always have some value for every row and for remaining you don't know how frequently the column will have value, as they are not mandatory.

In such cases I would separate the data by its probability of availability.

`Table_1 = Domain_Owner  --> DomainID, OwnerID`

`Table_2 = Domain_ExtraUser -->DominID,AdminID,TechID,BillingID`

`Table_3 = Contact --> ContactID`

Now in the above design `Table2` has same issue. As @JoelBrown mentioned when `NULL` ability is non-deterministic for column the performance of the queries against them will be unexpected until you do some testing.

If tables are not expected be huge like in millions of rows you can transform `Table_2` in to *key-value pair*.

`TABLE_2 = Domain_ExtraUser --> DomainID ,ContactID`

Comment: @AnupShap In your last suggestion I can't figure out how I'm going to separate the *contacts* between their roles? I also want to point one thing, if I wasn't clear enough, that a *domain* can have partial extra roles, meaning it can have **Admin** but none **Tech** or **Billing** and vice verca.